# Google Colab can't find file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i have a txt file i want to pass to a function in Google Colab. This is what i have so far

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

```
import os
import sys

GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH_AFTER_MYDRIVE = 'My_CW_folder' 
GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH = os.path.join('drive', 'My Drive', GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH_AFTER_MYDRIVE)
print(os.listdir(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH))
TRAIN_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/My_CW_folder/CW_Dataset/train'
LABEL_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/My_CW_folder/CW_Dataset/labels/list_label_train.txt'


CODE_PATH = os.path.join(GOOGLE_DRIVE_PATH, 'Code')
sys.path.append(CODE_PATH)
```

This is the cell that throws an error

```
from EmotionDetection import EmotionRecognition

EmotionRecognition(TRAIN_PATH, LABEL_PATH)
```

And this is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-78fc51fc0674> in <module>()
----> 1 from EmotionDetection import EmotionRecognition
      2 
      3 EmotionRecognition(TRAIN_PATH, LABEL_PATH)

2 frames

/content/drive/My Drive/My_CW_folder/Code/EmotionDetection.py in get_training_data(img_path, label_path)
     17 
     18 def get_training_data(img_path, label_path):
---> 19     label_file = open(label_path, 'r')
     20     lines = list(label_file)
     21     images = []

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CW_Dataset/labels/list_label_train.txt'
```

My guess is that when the code from line 19 is trying to execute, it either can't find the file, therefore can't open it. Or maybe files can't be open like that, through Google Colab???

Also here is how i structure my files:

[image]

Comment: error shows `'CW_Dataset/labels/list_label_train.txt'` - maybe you should use full path to this file.

Comment: yes i am not sure why but i did assign full path here LABEL_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/My_CW_folder/CW_Dataset/labels/list_label_train.txt'. And i am using this as a parameter for my function. I just tried passing tho whole path into the function instead of the variable, which should be the same thing but i got the same error.

Comment: error show `'CW_Dataset/labels/list_label_train.txt'` in `get_training_data()` so maybe puse `print()` to check values in variables in this function. And later find where this function is used and again use `print()` to see values in variable, etc. Maybe somewhere you remove part of full path. It is `"print debuging"`